# Smooth mouse scrolling and mouse cursor severly lag or are delayed when cpu usage is 100% on all cpu threads

Tags: asus

Laptop: Asus Zenbook UX305UA

OS: Windows 10

Problem: when cpu usage of the laptop is at 100% (especially when more threads are running/scheduled than there are cpu cores/threads -- this is often the case when multiple multi-threaded apps run at the same time), the mouse smooth scrolling and "handling" is severely delayed or outright non-responding. This can be reproduced by running a CPU-Z multithreaded benchmark and trying to scroll something in another app (e.g. a webpage in a browser).

I've already resolved the problem and am creating this question only for search engines to index it for me in the future to find it in case I forget (but also for anyone wanting to know how to approach this problem).

Comment: It is normal behavior for something to fall down the waterfall when the CPU has no more processing capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the Asus Smart Gesture app/process runs at an appropriate cpu priority. In my case, the process is consistently auto-ran on system startup at the "below normal" priority.

1. Open the Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc).
2. In the Processes tab, sort by name, and locate the "Asus Smart Gesture Center".
3. Right click on it and select "Go to details". The Details tab will open with the process preselected.
4. Right click on the preselected process (AsusTPCenter.exe) and hover over the "Set priority" submenu. It should show you what the current cpu priority the process is set to run at.
5. If the priority is "below normal" (or "normal" -- I recommend setting it to at least "above normal"), then this is the problem and the solution is described below.

I didn't find a way to make the AsusTPCenter.exe start with a different priority than it starts at. What I resorted to is that I wrote a batch script that sets the process' priority to "above normal", and I made that script auto-run on my user logon. See the following steps:

1. Create a .bat file anywhere.
2. Edit it.
3. Put the following inside:

```
wmic process where name="AsusTPCenter.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"
```

4. Save.
5. Open the Run window (Windows-Key + R).
6. Type shell:startup and press Enter. It opens a directory where one can put scripts to auto-run on user logon.
7. Either move the .bat file created in point 1 to that directory, or create a shortcut to that file, and put the shortcut there.
8. (optional) Run the batch file at least once to see if it does what it's supposed to do. I.e. ensure that the AsusTPCenter.exe process runs at any priority but "above normal", then double click on the .bat file, and finally recheck the priority of the process. It should now run on "above normal".
9. Restart the machine to confirm all the above worked.

Notes:

1. The regrettable fact is that Asus' touchpad driver is far from ideal. There are resources on the Internet reporting that using a different driver (that better integrates with Windows) doesn't have many of the Asus driver's problems. One such driver that those resources report is called "Elan".
2. Windows 11 is likely not affected by this problem (in case Asus decided to provide a touchpad driver that fully integrates with the Win11's touchpad native handling).
3. Links that helped me find this solution:

   1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/b1i6a6/how_do_i_get_rid_of_the_terrible_asus_smart/
   2. https://www.eightforums.com/threads/cpu-priority-shortcut-for-a-program-create-in-windows.40287/